# Android url in UTF8

Tags: android, url, utf-8

I am trying to download image using an url like:

```
url --> http://www.example.com/path/to/image-ğüçöşı.jpg

InputStream input = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

However in the first line app crashes. Because it has a character like "ı" or "ç". If url doesn't has those character it doesn't crash and works fine.
I could almost say i tried most of the solutions like utf8 encoding and etc, including giving "UTF8" params to HttpClient.

It would be appreciated very much if you could help me. I am looking for any solution that doesn't slow down the code very much.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode your url or only image name with this code

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("strangeChars", "utf-8");
```

Comment: I have tried this before, i tried again, doesn't work. It changes from  http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/orucu_bozan_durumlar2-168x137.jpg to http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F06%2Forucu_bozan_durumlar2-168x137.jpg

Comment: Would encoding only image name make any differences

Comment: My second idea is using URI.toASCIIString() method. Hope it will be better.